# Why official doc recommend to use componentDidMount instead of callback in setState?

Tags: reactjs

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

I have seem the official doc says :

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered. Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead.

why they recommend to use componentDidUpdate instead of callback when we need to use the latest state?

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidUpdate` is also invoked immediately after every updating occurs. At this time, latest state is updated.

Putting all checking state logics in `componentDidUpdate` is easier for managing than many `callback` with every `setState`.

By the way if you use `redux`, we will not do `setState` in your components.
[More about redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/ThreePrinciples.html)

Note: `componentDidUpdate`  is not called for the initial render.

Learn more Component life cycle https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: In summary, put the logic in componentDidUpdate is more easy to manage.

Comment: But I don't agree with you the next point, if I am using redux, I should not use setState. I still think if the state is just for UI to change,we can use setState to handle instead of putting all the data in redux and pass down to many layer components.

Comment: Using redux or not is depend on how big your application is. That article is useful for you https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367

Comment: I recently posted similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71504483/where-when-to-fetch-data-after-form-change-using-reactjs